# Compass guide to GPS destination

Tags: java, android, gps, compass-geolocation

I want to rotate an `ImageView` with an arrow from the current user location to some previously saved GPS location. How do I do this?

Is the Initial Bearing got from the `Location.distanceBetween` method the right way to go on this?  If so, how do I use it with the compass readings?

Comment: I'm looking for the same answer. Have you found something yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`bearingTo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#bearingTo%28android.location.Location%29) method in `Location` class,
then retrieve the current bearing using the [`SensorManager.getOrientation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getOrientation%28float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D%29) method.

Finally, adding both results, draw the arrow.

Hope it helps.